# Where can I find the hit points for vehicles?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, vehicles

In the PHB (pg. 157), it lists various [mounts and vehicles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#MountsandVehicles):

For the animals, such as horses and elephants, etc, their hit points can be found under their listings in the *Monster Manual*.

But what about the vehicles, such as wagons and boats? Where can I find the hit points for a row boat, for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the DMG includes a table for [Airborne and Waterborne Vehicles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/adventure-environments#AirborneandWaterborneVehicles), there appears to be no such thing for land vehicles — wagons, buggies, chariots, or whatever else. However, there is a table for [Object Hit Points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/running-the-game#ObjectHitPoints), which includes:

> **Size**: Large (cart, 10-ft.-by-10-ft. window) **Fragile:**  5 (1d10) **Resiliant:** 27 (5d10)

This is a little less than satisfying from a simulation-model point of view, since a large cart (27hp?) seems like it ought to be a lot more sturdy than many rowboats, which are given on the first table as having 50hp. But, there it is. On the other hand, the rowboat has an AC of 11 (normally for objects made of cloth, paper, or rope), while the [Object Armor Class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/running-the-game#ObjectArmorClass) table gives AC 15 for objects made from wood or bone (both perfectly lovely construction materials for a wagon, right?) so maybe that balances out well enough.

It's also important to observe that the object rules include the concept of **Damage Threshold** — a limit below which any single dose of damage is considered superficial and not counted. On the first chart above, a rowboat has no damage threshold, while a longship is much more sturdy with 300hp and a damage threshold of 15.

Comment: I was all set to use this answer as reference in our current game, but then I realized the DMG section on Objects specifies:

`For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, not a building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.`

Why they list cart as an example of a large object, I do not know.

Answer (score 18):

### In the Dungeon Master's Guide

The Dungeon Master's Guide includes a table with statistics for several water vehicles on page 119 (or [online in D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/adventure-environments#AirborneandWaterborneVehicles)). These include the rowboat but unfortunately not a wagon.